# If Lagarias' inequality is wrong, are there infinitely many counterexamples to it?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, divisor-sum

I do know that since Robin's (RI) and Lagarias' (LI) inequalities are both equivalent to RH, they're also equivalent one another, hence  if RI is false, so is LI. And Robin proved there are infinitely many counterexamples to RI, if it ever fails. Does this imply, or at least, was this used to prove that it is true for LI as well? 
In other words, I may ask you if it is known that all the colossally abundant numbers greater than the first counterexample to LI violate it too. Thank you in advance.

Comment: you would have a better time with the criterion of Nicolas, item 83 at http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/publications.html  and  discussed in http://arxiv.org/abs/1012.3613

Comment: Alright, thanks. But as for the question, is the answer positive?